# Pass value from one tab to another tab in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on ReactJS and was wondering on how can I pass value between tabs.

Below is the component I am working on. I have three tab and want to pass the card from one tab to another on clicking accept button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DriverPlacedOrder from './DriverPlacedOrder';
import {Link }from 'react-router-dom';
import {Tabs,Tab} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class Driver extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      key: 'home',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs
        id="controlled-tab-example"
        activeKey={this.state.key}
        onSelect={key => this.setState({ key })}
      >
        <Tab eventKey="newOrder" title="New Order">

         <div class="container">
                <div class="card" style={{width:'100%',borderRadius:'2%', border: '4px solid lightgreen'}}>
                    <div class="card-body" style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                        <h4 class="card-title">{CID}</h4>
                        <p class="card-text"><h5>{RID}</h5></p>
                        <Button variant="outline-success"onClick={} style={{width:'33%'}}><i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i><br/>Accept</Button>
                        <Button variant="outline-primary" style={{width:'33%'}}><i class="fas fa-book-open fa-lg" fa-lg></i><br/>View</Button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="currentOrder" title="Current Order">

        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="orderHistory" title="OrderHistory">

        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Onclicking accept button how can I pass card from NewOrder tab to currentOrder tab?

Comment: If it's the same domain, you can use localStorage. I'd also look into SockIO if you're looking for some real time communication.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on ReactJS and was wondering on how can I pass value
>   between tabs.

```
<Tab my_data={my_data_value} eventKey="orderHistory" title="OrderHistory">
</Tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to re-use the card markup for each tab, and also allow navigation between tabs via that same card markup.

One way to achieve that would be to define a method such as `renderCard()` that renders that common markup. You'd then call that method when rendering the contents of each `<Tab>` component. Something to keep in mind also is that `renderCard()` may need a parameter to specify which tab the "Accept" button navigates to:

```
export default class Driver extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { key: 'newOrder' };
    }

    /* Define render card function. Takes nextKey parameter that controls what tab the Accept button will navigate to */
    renderCard(nextKey) {
        return (<div class="card" style={{width:'100%',borderRadius:'2%', border: '4px solid lightgreen'}}>
            <div class="card-body" style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                <h4 class="card-title">{'CID'}</h4>
                <p class="card-text"><h5>{'RID'}</h5></p>
                <Button variant="outline-success"onClick={ () => {
                this.setState({ key : nextKey })
                }} style={{width:'33%'}}><i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-lg"></i><br/>Accept</Button>
                <Button variant="outline-primary" style={{width:'33%'}}><i class="fas fa-book-open fa-lg" fa-lg></i><br/>View</Button>
            </div>
        </div>)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Tabs
            id="controlled-tab-example"
            activeKey={this.state.key}
            onSelect={key => this.setState({ key })}>
            <Tab eventKey="newOrder" title="New Order">
                <div class="container">
                { /* Render card, and specify which tab the card's accept button will navigate to */ }
                { this.renderCard('currentOrder') }
                </div>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="currentOrder" title="Current Order">
                <div class="container">
                { /* Render card if this tab visible */ }
                { this.renderCard('orderHistory') }
                </div>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="orderHistory" title="OrderHistory">
                <div class="container">
                { /* Render card if this tab visible */ }
                { this.renderCard('newOrder') }
                </div>
            </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for passing the card which was previously on NewOrder Tab, and on pressing accept button, the card should move to Current Order tab, Similarly pressing accept button should move the card to orderHistory tab from Current Order. Any help would be highly appreciated. @Dacre Denny

Comment: The code above should achieve this effect. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your requirements?

Comment: It will change the tab but won't pass the card to another tab. If you see my code above I have a card in the NewOrder tab. And when I click accept button on the card, card should move from NewOrder tab to Current order tab. And then from CurrentOrder tab to orderhistory tab. @Dacre Denny

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding. The code in my answer will render the card so that it's visible on which ever tab is active. When the accept button is clicked, that triggers the `<Tabs>` component to change the active tab, where the card is "transferred" to that new active/visible `<Tab/>`. Apologies for the misunderstanding :)